# Second thread doesn't run until first is completed

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to implement a producer/consumer type thing where the producer thread grabs characters out of a string and puts them in a circular linked list queue (5 nodes large) and the consumer thread reads in the characters and prints them to the screen. Both threads stop when they reach a new line character. The problem I'm having is that the consumer thread never starts until the producer thread terminates.

```
int consumer_thread_alive;
...

void * producer(struct Node * head)
{
    while (consumer_thread_alive == 0)
    {
        printf("Waiting on consumer.");
    }
...
}

void * consumer(struct Node * head)
{
    consumer_thread_alive = 1;
...
}
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    consumer_thread_alive = 0;
    pthread_t produce;
    pthread_t consume;
    printf("Creating producer thread.\n");
    pthread_create(&produce, NULL, (void *) producer(&head), NULL );
    printf("Creating consumer thread.\n");
    pthread_create(&consume, NULL, (void *) consumer(&head), NULL );
    pthread_join(produce,NULL);
    pthread_join(consume,NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

I cut out some of the other parts, but thats where I'm having trouble (head gets initialized earlier on in main). If I run the code as it is it prints out "Creating producer thread." and then continually prints out "Waiting on Consumer." until I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and stop it. Also, if I remove the loop in the top of the producer thread, it run through all of its iterations and then the consumer thread gets called. For whatever reason its running serially instead of parallel.

Comment: You cannot synchronize threads with a plain `int` variable. You have to use proper synchronization primitives.

Comment: The call to `pthread_create()` is wrong.

Comment: Don't ignore your compiler's warnings, and don't just try killing the warnings with casts.  (Occasionally, a cast is correct, but more often than not it is the wrong solution to the problem that is being diagnosed.)  Remember, the compiler knows more about C than you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
pthread_create(&produce, NULL, (void *) producer(&head), NULL );
```

to be:

```
pthread_create(&produce, NULL, producer, &head);
```

(same for the consumer)

---

And: You should always test the outcome of system calls!

---

And^2: Protect the concurrent access to `consumer_thread_alive` by using a mutex, for example!

---

And^3: The thread function ougth to have the following form:

```
void * thread_func(void *);
```

So your implementation of the producer's thread function may start like:

```
void * producer(void * pvhead)
{
  struct Node * head = pvhead;
  ...
```

But be aware, that as you are **passing** a reference to **the same** instance of `struct Node` **to both** of the threads, so the concurrent **access** to it inside the thread functions **needs to be protected** as well (see *And^2*  above).

Comment: Thanks! Changing the pthread_create did the trick and now it does what I want it to. And I took out the consumer_thread_alive integer. I only added it to help diagnose my problem and I'm actually using a conditional variable and a mutex to protect the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread, const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
          void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

above syntax is declared for `pthread_create`in `#include <pthread.h>` header file.

so you have to change the following to work

```
   pthread_create(&produce, NULL, producer, (void *)&head);
```

FULL WORKING CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void * producer(void * );
void * consumer(void * );
struct node{
int x;
};
struct node head;
int consumer_thread_alive;
void * producer(void * head)
{
    printf("producer\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);    
}
void * consumer(void * head)
{
    consumer_thread_alive = 1;
    printf("consumer\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    consumer_thread_alive = 0;
    pthread_t produce;
    pthread_t consume;
    printf("Creating producer thread.\n");
    pthread_create(&produce, NULL, producer, (void*)&head );
    printf("Creating consumer thread.\n");
    pthread_create(&consume, NULL, consumer, (void*)&head );
    pthread_join(produce,NULL);
    pthread_join(consume,NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_create(//producer's)
pthread_join(//producer's)
pthread_create(//consumer's)
pthread_join(//consumer's)
```

this order would work.

EDIT: This worked when I did try to implement the same thing. Just give it a try.

Comment: No; this is not sensible.  The producer won't exit until the consumer is started, so the join first won't work.